# python timestamp doesn't update

Tags: python, timestamp

my `time.ctime()` is not changing when executing my program each 5 second.

How can I fix it?

My program:

```
import random
import time

n = 1
future = time.time() + 600

for x in range(5):  # program execute 5 times
    print(n)
    print time.ctime(future)
    sensor1 = {'ID': 'A', 'float1': ['A' + str(i) for i in range(1, 17)]}
    print(sensor1)
    count = 16  # represents 16 float readings
    for i in range(0, count):
        r = random.random()  # generates random real number between 0 and 1
        print(r)

    sensor2 = {'ID': 'B', 'float1': ['B' + str(i) for i in range(1, 17)]}
    print(sensor2)
    count = 16  # represents 16 float readings
    for i in range(0, count):
        r = random.random()  # generates random real number between 0 and 1
        print(r)
    time.sleep(5)  # to wait a second
    n = n + 1
```

Comment: You are setting the value of 'future' just once, outside the loop. That's what you must fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you set a fixed value *future*, and you are using the same fixed value again and again.

You can print the current time using:

```
print time.ctime()
```

You can print the current time + 600 using:

```
print time.ctime(time.time() + 600)
```

---

> [python time manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) specify:
>
> `time.ctime([secs])`
>
> Convert a time expressed in seconds since the epoch to a string
>   representing local time. If secs is not provided or None, the current
>   time as returned by `time()` is used. `ctime(secs)` is equivalent to
>   `asctime(localtime(secs))`. Locale information is not used by `ctime()`.

---

Example Code (e.g. saved as `time_prints.py`):

```python
import time

for x in range(5):  # program execute 5 times
    print time.ctime()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Example output:

```
$ python time_prints.py 
Thu Feb  8 14:37:41 2018
Thu Feb  8 14:37:46 2018
Thu Feb  8 14:37:51 2018
Thu Feb  8 14:37:56 2018
Thu Feb  8 14:38:01 2018
```

Comment: ok, but I am still getting a fix time in the loop. I want it to be different each five minute as timesleep (5) second. could you help me to get a good code, please.

Comment: @BovarinBoukedy - updated my answer with an example code + output

Comment: @BovarinBoukedy - did I answer your question?